# count or id's for name breaking up when adding another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

The ID count for Name changes when I add a 3rd column.  Is there a way to keep the count even after adding the 3rd column?

Lets say I have following:

```
Name   ID   Status
A .    12 . ffdsds
A .    32 . rtrwtr
B .    33 . ytrtre
B .    43 . jkljkj
B .    22   gerewr
C .    12 . trtrtr
```

I want results to show as:

```
Name CNT  ID   Status
A .  2    12 . ffdsds
A .  2 .  32 . rtrwtr
B .  3    33 . ytrtre
B .  3    43 . jkljkj
B .  3    22   gerewr
C .  1.   12 . trtrtr
```

I tried to "count" the ID and gives me the correct count for the Name, but when I add the Status, it shows 1 for all the Name.  Is there a way to show it like above?

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the count currently? A calculated column? An implicit measure?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me...  I am just selecting the dropdown under Values and selecting "count".  this returns 2, 3 and 1 for A, B and C which is correct, but when I add Status, it all turns into 1.  I am trying to use the "New Quick Measure" but without success

Comment: Is there a way to say, give me a count of ID's for Name no matter what is added after the Count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to actually write a measure. Currently, it's including the `Status` as part of the filter context so there's only one count per `Status`.

Try defining a measure as follows:

```
CNT = CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Table1[ID] ),  ALLEXCEPT ( Talble1, Table1[Name] ) )
```

This will keep just the `Name` filter context but ignore `Status` and any other filtering.

Comment: Thanks Alexis!  seems like such an easy thing but struggled with it for so long